# How can I dynamically remove an Observable from a combineLatest operator?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I use angular and I have some array that gets dynamically populated with `Observable`, so let's say that on:

- time 1 I get an `Observable` `a$` setted to `false` that should return `true`
- time 2 I get an `Observable` `b$` setted to `false` that should return `true`

now I have an array like so: `[ a$, b$ ]`. Then I use the `combineLatest` operator to wait till all the observables are completed and return true ( I've added `filter` and `take` operators ). But now let's see what's happening.

- time 4 `Observable` `b$` emits true ( `combineLatest` is not streaming anything )
- time 5 `Observable` `a$` is deleted from my waiting list and I don't need it anymore I try remove all references to it
- time 6 `combineLastest` is stuck because `Observable` `a$` will not emit a `true` value and should be deleted but `combineLatest` is still using an array with `a$` inside of it.

So basically my question is How can dynamically remove and element used in a combineLatest operator in order to make it complete?

The example I've shown you is with two `Observable` but it could be more than that.

Comment: Are you trying to race two observables? There's an operator for that.

Comment: @MrkSef what do you mean by racing two observables?

Comment: @MrkSef I've looked at the `race` operator and that is not at all what I'm trying to achieve here or I'm misunderstanding.My goal basically is to say "I have 3 observable -> complete when all are true" with the ability to remove one or more resulting in the observable to complete when remaining observables have emitted `true`

Comment: What's stopping you from deleting an observable by making it emit true?

Comment: @MrkSef it's not a bad idea but this break the whole logic or let's say the meaning of the code.I have peers connected and the observable is callled `isConnected$`, if I delete it and just before trigger `isConnected$` to `true`this is changing the meaning of things.This is a possible solution but If there are more meaningful alternatives I would prefer them.any ideas?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you explained what the actual scenario is instead of just `a$` and `b$` and 'waiting list'. Also, how is the deletion of the possible future value handled in when `combineLatest` would emit? Alot of unclear info here. There might be a possibility that you're not even needing an array thats "dynamically populated", but instead could achieve this with different type of special type of observables such as subjects. Care to rephrase to explain what the scenario is?

Comment: @DanielB, I've answered the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MrkSef I've answered the question thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've finally followed most of the comment of the comment of [Mrk Sef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13500986/mrk-sef)

> What's stopping you from deleting an observable by making it emit
> true?

```
combineLatest( [
  peer.isOpened$,
  peer.isClosed$
] ).pipe(
     filter( ( [ isOpened, isClosed ] ) => isOpened || isClosed ),
     take( 1 ) 
   )
```

if I delete the peer I set `isClosed$` to `true`, I would have prefered an alternative but if that's the only way.